# Add timestamps in python

Tags: python

How to add The following timestamps month wise in python 2.4 i.e, all the timestamps occurring in month 3 should be added together.

For example: the result should be like on 2011-03 total timestamp is 1:00:45 and so on for other months..

```
2011-03-07  0:27:41
2011-03-06  0:13:41
2011-03-08  0:17:40
2011-03-04  0:55:40
2011-05-16  0:55:40
2011-05-18  0:55:40
2011-07-16  0:55:40
2011-07-17  0:55:40
```

Comment: Where do you get these data? Do they come in this text format? Are the dates sorted? Also, I can't reproduce your calculation.

Comment: So the first column is the date, the second column the time in h:m:s worked on that date? You want to sum up the hours worked in a given month?

Comment: The dates are sorted and its of datetime format.Yes i want to sum up the hours worked in a given month

Comment: Please the edit in timestamps..this is the exact data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
import datetime
import re
from collections import defaultdict
months = defaultdict(int)
# months = {}  # for Python 2.4
with open("test.txt") as timestamps:
    for line in timestamps:
        month = line[:7]
        time = re.search(r"(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)", line)
        if time:
             seconds = int(time.group(1))*3600 + \
                       int(time.group(2))*60 +   \
                       int(time.group(3))
             months[month] += seconds
             # if month in months:          # Python 2.4
             #     months[month] += seconds
             # else:
             #     months[month] = seconds
for month in sorted(months.keys()):
    print("Times for {}: {}".format(month, 
                                    datetime.timedelta(seconds=months[month])))
```

Output:

```
Times for 2011-03: 1:54:42
Times for 2011-05: 1:51:20
Times for 2011-07: 1:51:20
```

Comment: Python 2.4 doesnt have thedefaultdict.rit.Is there any other way for this

Comment: Why are you using 2.4? It's several years old. (If you have to, just use a normal dict, and use `.setdefault()` or check before adding to an entry whether that entry is already present).

Comment: We use RHEL5 and python on it is 2.4v and even our servers are ancient

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is already sorted, you could use itertools.groupby:

```
import datetime as dt
import itertools as it

data='''\
2011-03-07  0:27:41
2011-03-06  0:13:41
2011-03-08  0:17:40
2011-03-04  0:55:40
2011-05-16  0:55:40
2011-05-18  0:55:40
2011-07-16  0:55:40
2011-07-17  0:55:40
'''.splitlines()

dates=[dt.datetime.strptime(line,'%Y-%m-%d %X') for line in data]
for key,group in it.groupby(dates,lambda d: (d.year,d.month)):
    seconds=sum(date.hour*3600+date.minute*60+date.second for date in group)
    print('{k[0]}-{k[1]:02d} {d}'.format(
        k=key,
        d=dt.timedelta(seconds=seconds)))
```

yields

```
2011-03 1:54:42
2011-05 1:51:20
2011-07 1:51:20
```

And (of course) if the data is not already sorted, then you could just sort it with `dates.sort()` before using `itertools.groupby`.

Comment: I get an error as for key,group in it.groupby(dates,lambda d: (d.tm_year(),d.tm_month())):
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: @Rajeev: remove the parentheses in `d.tm_year()` and `d.tm_month()`. What kind of object is `d`? What is `tm_year`, `tm_month`...?

Answer (score 1):

Both of this solutions - AFAIK - should work on any 2.x version of python (thus guaranteeing quite some backward compatibility)

An implementation that only depends on the **regex library**:

```
import re
data = '''
2011-03-07  0:27:41
2011-03-06  0:13:41
2011-03-05  0:17:40
2011-03-04  0:55:40
2011-05-16  0:55:40
2011-05-16  0:55:40
2011-07-16  0:55:40
2011-07-16  0:55:40
'''
def group(month):
    li = re.findall(r'2011-%s-\d\d  (\d+:\d+:\d+)' % str(month).zfill(2), data)
    seconds = 0
    for log in li:
        log = [int(n) for n in log.split(':')]
        seconds += log[0]*3600 + log[1]*60 + log[2]
    hours = seconds / 3600
    seconds -= 3600*hours
    minutes = seconds / 60
    seconds -= 60*minutes
    return "%02d:%02d:%02d" % (hours, minutes, seconds)

for month in range(1,13):
    print "In month %d you worked %s" % (month, group(month))
```

And here an implementation **without dependencies**:

```
def group(month):
    to_find = '2011-%s-' % str(month).zfill(2)
    logs = []
    for line in data.split('\n'):
        point = line.find(to_find)
        if point != -1:
            logs.append(line[-8:])
    seconds = 0
    for log in logs:
        log = [int(n) for n in log.split(':')]
        seconds += log[0]*3600 + log[1]*60 + log[2]
    hours = seconds / 3600
    seconds -= 3600*hours
    minutes = seconds / 60
    seconds -= 60*minutes
    return "%02d:%02d:%02d" % (hours, minutes, seconds)
```