# Add timestamps in python month wise

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add timestamps in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775811/add-timestamps-in-python)

```
dates = {} 
dates.update({'2011-03-07':'16:03:01'})
dates.update({'2011-03-06':'16:03:01'})
dates.update({'2011-03-08':'16:03:01'})
dates.update({'2011-03-04':'16:03:01'})
dates.update({'2011-05-16':'16:03:01'})
dates.update({'2011-05-18':'16:03:01'})
dates.update({'2011-07-16':'16:03:01'})
dates.update({'2011-07-17':'16:03:01'})
```

From the above dictionary how to how to add the all the timestamps for a particular month in `python2.4`

Comment: this scenario is very different from that one that is the reason i posted a new post..

Comment: Not really very different... but OK, if I get to recycle my code from over there, no problem :)

Comment: Yes but i think this would be very different  :)

Comment: @Rajeev: You can't "think" it would be very different.  You must **write** -- in the question -- precisely the way it is different.  Please **edit** the question to explain how this is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime
import re
months = {}
for date in dates:
    month = date[:7]
    time = re.match(r"(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)", dates[date])
    seconds = int(time.group(1))*3600 + int(time.group(2))*60 + int(time.group(3))
    if month in months:
        months[month] += seconds
    else:
        months[month] = seconds
for month in sorted(months.keys()):
    print "Times for " + month + ": " + str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=months[month]))
```

Output:

```
Times for 2011-03: 2 days, 16:12:04
Times for 2011-05: 1 day, 8:06:02
Times for 2011-07: 1 day, 8:06:02
```

Comment: Oops, I just fixed an error (use `str` instead of `repr`).

Answer (score 1):

It may be solved without RegExps:

```
# dates = { ... } 

from datetime import datetime

stamps = []
for date, time in dates.iteritems():
    stamps.append(datetime.strptime('%s %s' % (date, time), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

def month_stamps(stamps, month):
    return filter(lambda x: x.month == month, stamps)

print month_stamps(dates_list, 5)
```

Comment: `stamps = [datetime.strptime('%s %s' % (date, time), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for date, time in dates.iteritems()]` and
`return [stamp for stamp in stamps if stamp.month == month]` and `print month_stamps(stamps, 5)`