# python: difference of two timedate strings

Tags: python, datetime, datediff

I have two date strings (taken from user input and can vary greatly)

```
s1 = '2011:10:01:10:30:00'
s2 = '2011:10:01:11:15:00'
```

I wish to find the difference between the two as minutes.

How should I proceed to tackle this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788807/add-timestamps-in-python-month-wise This would help u resolve the issue

Comment: A quick Google search dug up this library: http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxDateTime/ - It seems to have the ability to process arbitrary formats, which you mentioned might be a requirement for you. I think the standard datetime libraries you have to specify an exact format to parse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import datetime

d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2011:10:01:10:30:00', '%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S')
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2011:10:01:11:15:00', '%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S')
diff = (d2 - d1).total_seconds() / 60
```

If you need to handle arbitrary datetime formats, I don't believe the built in datetime library will do that for you.  Perhaps check out something like:

http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxDateTime/

Answer (score 5):

Using the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) module, parse into a [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#date-objects) object using [`strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), then subtract. You'll get a [`timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta). Then use `timedelta.total_seconds()` and divide by 60.

Answer (score 4):

Use [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) to parse the string and convert into a base epoch time. Do the math. Convert back:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> s1 = '2011:10:01:10:30:00'
>>> s2 = '2011:10:01:11:15:00'
>>> d1=datetime.strptime(s1,'%Y:%m:%d:%I:%M:%S')
>>> d2=datetime.strptime(s2,'%Y:%m:%d:%I:%M:%S')
>>> d2-d1
datetime.timedelta(0, 2700)
>>> (d2-d1).total_seconds()/60
45.0
```

If you are looking for arbitrary date string parsing, check out [DateUtil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) and the [parse function](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-a23e8ae0a661d77b89dfb3476f85b26f0b30349c).

Answer (score 2):

The `time` module can be helpful for this.

```
import time

s1 = '2011:10:01:10:30:00'
s2 = '2011:10:01:11:15:00'

s1Time = time.strptime(s1, "%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S")
s2Time = time.strptime(s2, "%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S")

deltaInMinutes = (time.mktime(s2Time) - time.mktime(s1Time)) / 60.0
print deltaInMinutes, "minutes"
```