# How to find difference between two dates which are in string format in Python?

Tags: python

Suppose I have two strings say A and B whose values are as mentioned below

```
A = '24 06 2020 12:45'
B = '14 05 2020 12:45'
```

How can er find difference between them in terms of Hours.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python: difference of two timedate strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601781/python-difference-of-two-timedate-strings)

Comment: You can use the datetime module, and strftime() with the format matching your input values. using c = a - b and c.total_seconds()/3600 can give you the hours.

Simple example: 

    'datetime.timedelta(days=1).total_seconds()'

86400.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from datetime import datetime   
A = '24 06 2020 12:45'
B = '14 05 2020 12:45'
A = datetime.strptime(A,"%d %m %Y %H:%M")
B = datetime.strptime(B,"%d %m %Y %H:%M")
```

To get `hours` from `seconds` as follows:

```
print((A - B).total_seconds() // 3600)
```

I just added '//' instead of '/' for dividing so that I get the exact Number of hours

Comment: They were looking for hours, I would just add this ```print((a_date - b_date).total_seconds()/3600)``` or even ```print(str((a_date - b_date).days * 24) + " hours")```

Comment: @user7298979, thanks for pointing out me. I've updated. but calculating hours from days would go wrong sometimes if input hours are not matched exactly.

Comment: @NarendraPrasath thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If your timedate format is different then the ones the existing libraries can handle you can write a short program using `.split()` to seperate the string into an array and `int()` to transform the string into an integer

```py
A=A.split()
day=int(A[0])
month=int(A[1])
year=int(A[2])
time=A[3])
hour=int(time.split(':')[0])
minute=int(time.split(':')[1])
```

You can use that to either calculate the difference in seconds or only the difference in years ...